# How to use more than one JSF form

Tags: forms, jsf

I have a Java EE 7 project and in web application part I am trying to open JSF forms.

However when I run it, it just sees the initial form.

How can I enable it to reach other forms?

Small example from my code:

```
<body>
    <h:form id="firstForm" prependid="false">
        ...
    </h:form>
    <h:form id="secondForm" prependid="false">
        ...
    </h:form>
</body>
```

Comment: Show us the code. What have you tried yet?

Comment: I put an example into my question

Comment: that's weird. if you remove the `prependid=false`, do you still get the same behavior?

Comment: thanks for suggestion but yes still same behavior...

Comment: What do you mean by "sees initial form"? Are you attempting to submit an action and it fails? Please describe exactly what the symptoms are

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10744054/how-to-prevent-jsf2-injection-of-hidden-javax-faces-viewstate) helped me a lot. And also there were some referance problem. After correcting them, I can see all the form structure.

I know the code above is not nested form structure, but for other people who are curious about this issue, you cannot make nested forms in `HTML5` (for both `<h:form>` and `<form>`). So be careful to your template.

Good luck!